# 13900K. Erroneous heat issues - Strange temperature management behavior

Tags: cpu, bios, cpu-temperature

My computer will believe the cpu temperature is 95-100 degrees on all 24 cores of my 13900k at system idle - even only in bios.

it will operate like this for a minute or two. even preventing the computer to load bios to protect the chip.

i will wait a couple minutes to boot again. it will load windows fine and ill pull up my thermal monitoring program. it will show all cores at 95+.

then inexplicably, all temperatures will drop instantaneously to 28 degrees. not in a period of a few seconds. instantly from one update to the other the temperatures across the entire chip will drop 70 degrees. this happens every few days for a short time and it resolves.

I run benchmark software to test the cooling of my AIO and it never goes above 65 degrees under full load.

Is this a bios issue? is there an error with the chip? i dont think my CPU is actually running that hot, as the air coming from the case is quite cool. usually when its under load like that the machine is a small heater!

thanks for your time.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Could be an intermittent connection at one spot on the CPU, or elsewhere on the PC board. Reseat all connectors. If that doesn't help, you might test by pressing in different spots on the PCB with a soft-tipped insulated tool -- avoid too much pressure, or knocking off a surface-mount part.